# Take the mean of n numbers in a DataFrame column and "drag" formula down similar to Excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sliding-window

I'm trying to take the mean of n numbers in a pandas `DataFrame` column and "drag" the formula down each row to get the respective mean.

Let's say there are 6 rows of data with "Numbers" in column A and "Averages" in column B. I want to take the average of A1:A2, then "drag" that formula down to get the average of A2:A3, A3:A4, etc.

```py
    list = [55,6,77,75,9,127,13]
    finallist = pd.DataFrame(list)
    finallist.columns = ['Numbers']
```

Below gives me the average of rows 0:2 in the `Numbers` column. So calling out the rows with `.iloc[0:2])` works, but when I try to shift down a row it doesn't work:

```py
finallist['Average'] = statistics.mean(finallist['Numbers'].iloc[0:2])
```

Below I'm trying to take the average of the first two rows, then shift down by 1 as you move down the rows, but I get a value of `NaN`:

```py
    finallist['Average'] = statistics.mean(finallist['Numbers'].iloc[0:2].shift(1))
```

I expected the `.iloc[0:2].shift(1))` to shift the mean function down 1 row but still apply to 2 total rows, but I got a value of `NaN`.

Here's a screenshot of my output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening in your `shift(1)` approach is that you're actually shifting the index in your data "down" once, so this code:

```py
df['Numbers'].iloc[0:2].shift(1)
```

Produces the output:

```
0     NaN
1    55.0
```

Then you take the average of these two, which evalutes to `NaN`, and then you assign that single value to every element of the `Averages` Series here:

```py
df['Averages'] = statistics.mean(df['Numbers'].iloc[0:2].shift(1))
```

You can instead use [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) combined with `mean()` to get a sliding average across the entire data frame like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
values = [55,6,77,75,9,127,13]
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df.columns = ['Numbers']
df['Averages'] = df.rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()
```

This produces the following output:

```
    Numbers     Averages
0   55          55.0
1   6           30.5
2   77          41.5
3   75          76.0
4   9           42.0
5   127         68.0
6   13          70.0
```